# VPN Connection - How to view accessible directories in Windows?

Tags: networking, vpn, home-directory

I am using Nortel VPN Client to connect to a VPN. Now I can connect with my details, and my local ip I receive from the RAS server is: 192.168.22.44.

Now I am connected, so now what? How to I list possible directories that are accessible on the VPN LAN? Is there like some kind of net view or directory command I can use to see the possible directories I can access? Or even a remote server on that LAN?

I am connected, but I am totally 'blind' if you know what I mean...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Windows shares, you would machines names under your Windows Network.  You could then double click on them to see the shares.  Alternatively, if you know a share name, you could go directly to one with something like `\\machinename\sharename`

However, this is all assuming the VPN puts you on the same network as the machines with the shares.

Comment: thank you Keltari, but that is exactly the problem, I do not know the names of any shares...How do i find them? ALL I know is the local IP address I have as well as the public IP of the VPN server I connect to

Comment: Do you not see computers under Windows Network?

Comment: nope, none (apart from my own)

Comment: you need to talk to the network admins at the remote site

Comment: yup, I think so too...Any other way I can perhaps do this? I am at home currently and cannot reach the admins now

Comment: It sounds like the VPN network is segregated from everyhting else

Answer (score 0):

If you have connectivity to your local DNS servers, you can have the RAS issue the IP and DNS so they have access to your local network, then you could access resources on your network via DNS names etc...  (IE, net use to map drives, access server shares via \servername)  I believe that net view uses either netbios or WINS, so if you don't have WINS on your network and you're on a different broadcast domain, I don't think it will work.

Comment: thanks for the answer...but that is what I do not know - the DNS names of servers/files on the Remote server...I do not know what I can access...